# Why is the output from my CUDA program unreliable?

Tags: cuda

I am teaching myself CUDA with the programming guide that CUDA offers. For practice, I made a simple kernel that determines the maximum of an array and returns it to the CPU:

```
  __global__ void getTheMaximum(float* myArrayFromCPU, float* returnedMaximum) {
    // Store my current value in shared memory.
    extern __shared__ float sharedData[];
    sharedData[threadIdx.x] = myArrayFromCPU[threadIdx.x];

    // Iteratively calculate the maximum.
    int halfScan = blockDim.x / 2;
    while (halfScan > 0 && threadIdx.x < halfScan) {
      if (sharedData[threadIdx.x] < sharedData[threadIdx.x + halfScan]) {
        sharedData[threadIdx.x] = sharedData[threadIdx.x + halfScan];
      }
      halfScan = halfScan / 2;
    }

    // Put maximum value in global memory for later return to CPU.
    returnedMaximum[0] = sharedData[0];
  }
```

`myArrayFromCPU` is an array of float values of size 1024. `returnedMaximum` is a trivial array containing a single item: The computed maximum value.

My idea for this algorithm is that it would iteratively determine the maximum as it whittles down values from half the block size beyond the current value.

However, when I run this code, I get unreliable output. The returned maximum value varies. Why is that? How can a single algorithm produce different values every time?

Update:

I'm also just running on a single block. I guarantee this by setting a 1-dimensional block size of X=1024.

Comment: Keep the warps of thread-block synchronized. use `__syncthreads()` at the end of each `while` iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just running on a single block though. Do I still have to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not guaranteed that all threads of the whole block execute at the very same moment in time. That guarantee you have only within a single warp (group of 32 threads).

To avoid concurrency hazards within a block - you can use `__syncthreads()` intrinsic function which halts the threads reaching it until all reach the point.
Note, you should not put `__syncthreads()` in a branching code where you cannot guarantee that all threads will reach the spot uniformly.

Try the following loop:

```
__syncthreads();
while (halfScan > 0) {
  if (threadIdx.x < halfScan) {
    if (sharedData[threadIdx.x] < sharedData[threadIdx.x + halfScan]) {
      sharedData[threadIdx.x] = sharedData[threadIdx.x + halfScan];
    }
  }
  __syncthreads();
  halfScan = halfScan / 2;
}
```

Do note, that I removed the condition `threadIdx.x < halfScan` from the while loop, because I want *all* threads to execute `__syncthreads()` at the same spot and the same number of times.

Also, `__syncthreads()` before the loop may help to ensure that the load from `myArrayFromCPU` is complete (for all threads) before the loop starts.

Comment: I'm just using a single block though. Do I still have to sync my threads?

Comment: Unless block has only 1 warp (32 threads) you have to sync the threads. In CUDA, you use `__syncthreads()` to synchronize warps within a single block. You actually cannot (cleanly) synchronize threads between different blocks at all.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! That clears up my view of a warp and a block a lot. So threads within a warp are executed sequentially? By the way, I just realized... if I call `returnedMaximum[0] = sharedData[0];`, am I writing to global memory many, many times?

Comment: Threads within a warp are executed in parallel, but several warps within a block can happen to execute concurrently (mind that Fermi and Kepler can also run 2 or 4 warps at once). Yes, `returnedMaximum[0] = sharedData[0]` will issue `blockDim` writes. You can add `if (threadIdx.x==0)` in front of it --- it's a typical pattern.